# Node can't find dependency after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, digital-ocean, ghost

I am new to Node.js and hitting this problem on my DigitalOcean VPS, where my web app (Ghost) complains it can't find specific modules even after I install it:

```
root@3fen:/var/www/ghost# sudo npm install -g ghost-gql
ghost-gql@0.0.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ghost-gql
└── lodash@3.10.1

root@3fen:/var/www/ghost# node index.js
ERROR: Ghost is unable to start due to missing dependencies:
  Cannot find module 'ghost-gql'
  Cannot find module 'jsonpath'

Please run `npm install --production` and try starting Ghost again.
Help and documentation can be found at http://support.ghost.org.
```

I confirmed that both entries exist in `package.json`'s dependencies block, and I also tried `npm install --production`, it executes silently and still get the same error.

Please point me if I am missing anything in the above steps. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try running node REPL and see if require('ghost-gql') and require('jsonpath') are working

Comment: @prasun nope, both gives me `Cannot find module` error :(

Comment: I think its failing on path - try this and see if REPL works :: export PATH="$(npm bin):$PATH"

Comment: Did you try to link the node modules to your current project ? You are installing them globally , after that you'll need to link them to your project if you are require them in some node script .

Comment: @prasun Just tried it but seems not working either:  `root@3fen:/var/www/ghost# export PATH="$(npm bin):$PATH"
root@3fen:/var/www/ghost# node
> require("jsonpath")
Error: Cannot find module 'jsonpath'`

Comment: what folder path are you getting for "npm config get prefix"

Comment: @prasun `/usr/local`

Comment: set your environment variable NODE_PATH to this path and should work

Comment: @prasun you mean `export NODE_PATH="/usr/local"`? seems still not working even after this... :(

Comment: export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/node_modules

Comment: @prasun it worked. thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it looks like global npm path is not set in the environment variable NODE_PATH.

which needs to be the path as in `npm config get prefix` concatenated with `node_modules`

In your case

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/node_modules
```